# Regex to match month name followed by year

Tags: regex

Is it possible to use a regex to match "February 2009", for example?

Comment: Is it allowed to match "Undecimber 15000"?

Comment: The restrictions are January - December, followed by 1990 - 2010.  Fortunately, non-english isn't a concern.

Comment: *followed by 1990 - 2010* — Is it intentional to have this tight upper limit? There's only 8 months left to 2011.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Along the lines of

```
\b(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|...|Dec(?:ember)?) (?:19[7-9]\d|2\d{3})(?=\D|$)
```

that's

```
\b                  # a word boundary
(?:                 # non-capturing group
  Jan(?:uary)?      # Jan(uary)
  |Feb(?:ruary)?    #
  |...              # and so on
  |Dec(?:ember)?    # Dec(ember)
)                   # end group
                    # a space
(?:                 # non-capturing group
  19[7-9]\d|2\d{3}  # 1970-2999
)                   # end group
(?=\D|$)            # followed by: anything but a digit or the end of string
```

Comment: OBTW, 1990-2010 is `(?:199\d|20[01]\d)`

Answer (score 33):

I had to work on this to match a few fringe examples, but I ended up using

```
(\b\d{1,2}\D{0,3})?\b(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|(Nov|Dec)(?:ember)?)\D?(\d{1,2}\D?)?\D?((19[7-9]\d|20\d{2})|\d{2})
```

to capture dates with word months in them

Comment: Just a minor thing, for the months instead of (Nov|Dec) it should be (?:Nov|Dec), or at least I had to change that in order for it to work with Python otherwise it was returning an empty [''] match

Comment: You can add (?i)(regex_part_to_make_case_insensitive) or (?i)regex_part_to_make_case_insensitive(?-i) depending on the regex processor you are using.

Answer (score 4):

Modifying Beerswiller's answer, if you want "st"/"nd"/"rd" variations:

`(\b\d{1,2}\D{0,3})?\b(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|(Nov|Dec)(?:ember)?)\D?(\d{1,2}(st|nd|rd|th)?)?(([,.\-\/])\D?)?((19[7-9]\d|20\d{2})|\d{2})*`

Comment: It also passes 34rth July 1999 as a valid date!

Comment: @ZujajMisbahKhan it is not possible to make all mathematical calculations in a regular expression to see which months have 28, 29, 30 or 31, also depending on whether the year is odd or not. For this you can take the resulting matched date and validate it with you language of choice functions.

Answer (score 3):

This regex accounts for some spacing around the comma.

Sometimes it's not always in the right place.

```
((\b\d{1,2}\D{0,3})?\b(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|(Nov|Dec)(?:ember)?)\D?)(\d{1,2}(st|nd|rd|th)?)?((\s*[,.\-\/]\s*)\D?)?\s*((19[0-9]\d|20\d{2})|\d{2})*
```

Comment: I would suggest `Sep(?:t(?:ember)?)?`. I've seen Sept used in numerous datasets.

Answer (score 0):

The regex below will take into account the max number of days for the relevant month and also take into account leap years for February.

```
^(((0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[ ]\b(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|May|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Dec(?:ember)?)|(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|30)[ ]\b(?:Apr(?:il)?|Jun(?:e)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Nov(?:ember)?)|(0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])[ ]\b(?:Feb(?:ruary)?))[ ]\d{4}|29[ ]\b(?:Feb(?:ruary)?)[ ](\d{2}(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|([02468][048]|[1359][26])00))$
```

Answer (score 0):

January\s*\d{4}|February\s*\d{4}|March\s*\d{4}....and so on ...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).