# MM/DD Validation. It doesn't have YYYY also it should validates 02/30 which I'm unable too

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, knockout.js

```
function isMMDD(value) {
    var re = /^([0]?[1-9]|1[0-2])\/([0-2]?[0-9]|3[0-1])$/;
    if (re.test(value)) {
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

> I would like to have 02/30 as invalid too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular Expression to match valid dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51224/regular-expression-to-match-valid-dates)

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8768241/5894241) answer in particular. It handles the part about validating dates such as 02/30.

Answer (score 0):

With information in [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dates.html)

> If you are validating the user's input of a date in a script, it is
>   probably easier to do certain checks outside of the regex. For
>   example, excluding February 29th when the year is not a leap year is
>   far easier to do in a scripting language. It is far easier to check if
>   a year is divisible by 4 (and not divisible by 100 unless divisible by
>   400) using simple arithmetic than using regular expressions.

In your case it applies the same thing, also it is a very asked question.

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51224/regular-expression-to-match-valid-dates), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491894/regex-to-validate-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy) and also (but not exactly) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655476/regex-to-match-month-name-followed-by-year)

Comment: Hi @Rodrirokr thanks a lot for your explanation. I'm not that skilled to apply what you said above. Would you make it more clear and show me the code? Thanks in advance!