# How to include optional space between two words without picking next word?

Tags: regex

I have these below file names and using below regex to match:

File Names:

1. 1234 12345678 TEST DOCUMENT December 20, 2018.pdf
2. 1234 12345678 TESTDOCUMENT December 20, 2018.pdf

Regex I am using to match the file name is:

```
(\d+)\s(\d+)\s(\w+\s?\w+)
```

for the first file it is working, but for the 2nd file it is matching month December also as these are two words with a space too.

How to write a regex to match only upto "1234 12345678 TEST DOCUMENT" in both cases with or with out space between TEST and DOCUMENT.

Expected Result:

1. 1234 12345678 TEST DOCUMENT
2. 1234 12345678 TESTDOCUMENT

Not this for 2nd file(1234 12345678 TESTDOCUMENT December)

Comment: How are you expected to distinguish between those two cases?  Will it always say "TEST DOCUMENT" or might it be some other name?

Comment: It could be any text. Possible combination is two words with a space

Comment: Then I don't see how you can tell the difference between the two.  There aren't any distinguishing characteristics, unless you have something else like fixed columns.

Comment: After TEST DOCUMENT, it is always a month in format January-December

Comment: Ok.  Then part of your regex needs to match on all twelve month names, something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655476/regex-to-match-month-name-followed-by-year).  That will give you your ending demarcation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you said

> After TEST DOCUMENT, it is always a month in format January-December

You can use a lookahead to ensure that you don't match the month:

```
(\d+)\s(\d+)\s(\w+\s?(?!Jan|Feb|Mar|...|Dec)\w+)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...
```

This will ensure that the second word doesn't start with month names.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It can be any no of words before the month, but not only the second word. Is there any way to match it?

Comment: This worked. 

(\d+)\s(\d+)\s(.+?(?=January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December))

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to match the "datelike" format at the end and capture what is before in a capturing group:

`(\d+)\s(\d+)\s(.*?)\s\d{1,2},\s\d{4}\.pdf$`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nKO2AW/1)

As [@iBug](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5958455/ibug) points out, if you only want to match word characters or a whitespace you could replace `(.*?)` with `([\w ]+)`

Comment: `\w+` is better than `.*?`.

Comment: @iBug It depends on the content what is in between. In this case it could be `[\w ]+`. Added your suggestion to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure to always match the part with the date, for example:

```
(\d+)\s(\d+)\s(\w+\s?\w+)\s\w+\s\d+
```

Would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can select everything from the start of the line that is followed by (the lookahead `(?=...)`) a white space and the name of a month. Here is for november and december:

```
^.*(?= December| November)
```

Be careful with the cases of the month names (camelcase, upper, etc). Also, do you have localized data, months names in different languages...